# Can I use my website's mobile version as an app on ios/android market?

Tags: android, ios

I need to create an application for my website. but i have a mobile version of my website which is lighter and it's responsive(php/html/css)
the question is "Can i somehow create my Application by just importing or using this website?"
so that it has an icon and it seats next to other apps in mobile's menu. but when pressing the icon it loads in itself. I don't want it to use mobile's browser to show the website.

what i mean is a trick here , I don't design an app , but people think i have an app! and i shouldn't worry about the updates and platforms , while simply all i need to do is to maintain my website.

isn't that possible? any clue on how to achieve this?

Comment: So what happens when I have no internet?  I tap on the icon for this "app" and see just a white or black screen with nothing?  How about when I tap on a link which takes me to another page on your site and I have poor internet connection?  When I use a web browser, I expect these issues but if some app is trying to "trick" me into thinking Im looking at an app and not a web page, not gonna fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact possible, and can be achieved by creating a webview of your mobile site.
Assuming you know the basics of how to create the structure of an android application, the this is what you will need for your main activity's XML named "webview_paceholder"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview" <!-- The ID of your webview, can be wahtever you want. Just remember it for latter on --> 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And for your java class (if it is named WebView1):

```
package com.companyname.packagename;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;




public class WebView1 extends Activity {



    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_paceholder);


        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); // ID from earlier comment
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/whateveryourmobileviewis/"); // This url should be the mobile view of your site
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    }
```

If you do not know the basics of an android application, you can quickly learn to make one [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) for Eclipse and [Here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html) for Android Studio (recommended).
Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks , i'll give it a go and i'm sure this might solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ios app store doesn't generally allow apps that are just wrappers for a webpage. You'd need a good excuse for that, e.g. offering push notifications or some other enhanced functionality.

It is possible to make a web app appear more like an app (without the browser GUI, and with a nice icon) in ios. For example, utorrent does this with their [remote web interface](https://remote.utorrent.com/) to avoid app store restrictions. It still requires your users to bookmark your site to the homescreen.

Comment: tnx for mentioning this